# Delete records that is greater than time()

Tags: php, mysql, math, timestamp

I'm trying to delete records that has expired after 20 minutes, the column contains a timestamp which is `time()+1200` (20 minutes forward).

When I execute this query:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM " . SESSIONS_TABLE . "
        WHERE session_expire >= " . time() . "
        AND session_open = 1";
```

All of the records that has not passed the timestamp still get deleted... how come it's doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE condition is incorrect. You need to use..

```
WHERE session_expire <= " . time() . "
```

...otherwise, you're deleting sessions that are set to expire *after* the time provided.

Additionally, you could simply use MySQLs NOW function, if your database server's clock is in the same timezone, etc.

i.e.:

```
WHERE session_expire <= NOW()
```

Comment: Cheers... guess it's just my tiredness that made me think incorrectly, oops!

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to delete records that are **less** than `time()`.